# NullPointerException: Cannot invoke ServletRequestAttributes.getRequest because the return value of RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes is null

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, feign

I have a service, which uses a `RestTemplate` and for this it needs to get information from the Token.

```
public RoleKeycloak getRoleId(String idRole, String projectId) {

    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(URL, new HttpEntity<>(query, getHeaders()), String.class);
   //more operations 
}
```

I obtain the Headers information through a method getHeaders(), which uses a `FeignClientInterceptor`, which is responsible for obtaining authorization from the header.

```
private HttpHeaders getHeaders() {
    headers.set(ConstantsUtils.Authorization, FeignClientInterceptor.getBearerTokenHeader());
    headers.set(ConstantsUtils.Content_Type, ConstantsUtils.GraphQL);
    return headers;
}


@Component
public class FeignClientInterceptor implements RequestInterceptor {

      public static final String getBearerTokenHeader() {
          return ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest().getHeader(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER);
      }
}


    
@Test
void createRoleTest() throws ParseException, IOException {
String response = "createRoleProject";
    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<String>(response, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    
    given(restTemplate.postForEntity("myurl", getHeaders(), String.class))
        .willReturn(responseEntity);
    RoleKeycloak roleKeycloak = roleServiceKeycloak.createRole("admin", "idProject");
    assertNotNull(roleKeycloak);
}
```

I'm trying to test this method with `jUnit` but I can't, not even with the information on the internet. I'm trying to mock `FeignClientInterceptor` but I can't, always get a `NullPointerException` in RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();

Comment: your issue is you are unable to mock `getBearerTokenHeader` ? is that correct?

Comment: @AshishPatil yes, I’m trying to mock getBearerTokenHeader or instanciate in the tests something which avoid the NPE

Comment: So you don't have any issue with `FeignClientInterceptor ` right? you just need wanted to mock `getBearerTokenHeader ` so that whenever you call  `FeignClientInterceptor.getBearerTokenHeader()`, you get some response back in test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments & question, I am suggesting below solution:

Here, I am using mock static along with `MockHttpServletRequest` where in test case you can create a MockHttpServletRequest & set one header.
Later on, using mockStatic, you can enable stubbing for execution of `RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()`.

```
@Test
    void test() {
        MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
        request.addHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "SomeheaderValue");

        ServletRequestAttributes attributes = new ServletRequestAttributes(request);
        RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(attributes);

        RequestAttributes requestAttributes = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
        MockedStatic<RequestContextHolder> mockedStatic = mockStatic(RequestContextHolder.class);
        mockedStatic.when(() -> RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).thenReturn(requestAttributes);

        System.out.println(FeignClientInterceptor.getBearerTokenHeader()); // this will print "SomeheaderValue"
    }
```

You need to use below dependency to support mock static:

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

You can then directly call `FeignClientInterceptor.getBearerTokenHeader()` from `getHeaders` method in unit test.

Comment: What exactly should the 'mockStatic' method do? I can return a 'new MockedStatic<RequestContextHolder>(); ' which override many methods but I don't know who to implement  <S> OngoingStubbing<S> when(Verification verification)  method

Comment: you have static method in `FeignClientInterceptor`. I am just mocking it so that whenever you are calling your `getHeaders` , you will be calling mocked implementation of `((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest().getHeader(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER)`